# Build cpp code to run FFMPEG command in Anroid after generating .so file

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ndk, android-ffmpeg

I built `FFMPEG` so files(`libavcode.so, libavfilter.so, libavformat.so,libavutil.so, libswscale.so`) by following [this](https://proandroiddev.com/a-story-about-ffmpeg-in-android-part-i-compilation-898e4a249422) tutorial. This tutorial is nice is helpful to build your own `.so` files as per your library requirement.

**Why I am building own one?**
I know that there is some already available libraries in github like [bravobit's](https://github.com/bravobit/FFmpeg-Android), [tanersener's](https://github.com/tanersener/mobile-ffmpeg) and also [microshow's](https://github.com/microshow/RxFFmpeg). These all have certain limitations like some of this will not work for target SDK 29 & 30 and tanersener's lib is good but there is problems with `-filter_complex` command's output and micrshow's lib is crashing in android 10 and 11 beta! So, all have specific problems. So, I am considering to create own one.

**What I have and already done**
After following tutorial(mention in above) I successfully generated `.so` files and put it into my App.

Here is the screenshot of which I already done `.so` files:
[image: Put all files in cpp dir]

So, you can see that I put all files into cpp folder. As per version I only need ARMV7 and AMR64.

**What is the problem?**

Problem is that I have no idea how to create `.cpp` file to execute command and what is it actually and how to use it? I also tried some other libraries `.c` code but it didn't work for me. So, what is the code of `cpp` which can execute command? Is there any other way of this?

**Note of this requirement**
We can't run any executable file directly from directory in Android because its restricted in target Android 10 and 11. So, we compulsory need to build native code and call `class` or it's `function`.